# Updatelinks in Powerpoint from identical workbook in different directory (through vba?)

Tags: excel, vba, ms-office, powerpoint

I am working on linking charts in powerpoint (ppt) slides to charts in Excel (xls) workbooks. This works fine without vba code, as I just use paste special to  create a link. The problem is however when I change the directoy of the ppt as well as the xls, as the ppt will still try to update the data from the xls in the old directory. My goal however would be to share these files, so everyone can just update their ppt with their xls.

So, to put it shortly, I want to update the ppt, but choose a different workbook (with a different directory). This workbook will be identical to the old one in terms of structure, just with diffeerent data.

I know there is the method updatelinks, but there doesn't seem to be any way to choose a different directory with this method. Does anyone have any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So, to put it shortly, I want to update the ppt, but **choose** a different workbook (with a different directory). This workbook **will be identical** to the old one in terms of structure, just with different data.

**TRIED AND TESTED with MS-OFFICE 2010**

I have commented the code so that you will not have a problem understanding it. If you still do then feel free to ask.

```
Option Explicit

Sub UpDateLinks()
    '~~> Powerpoint Variables/Objects
    Dim ofd As FileDialog
    Dim initDir As String
    Dim OldSourcePath As String, NewSourcePath As String

    '~~> Excel Objects
    Dim oXLApp As Object, oXLWb As Object

    '~~> Other Variables
    Dim sPath As String, OldPath As String, sFullFileOld As String
    Dim oldFileName As String, newFileName As String

    'Set the initial directory path of File Dialog
    initDir = "C:\"

    '~~> Get the SourceFullName of the chart. It will be something like
    '   C:\MyFile.xlsx!Sheet1![MyFile.xlsx]Sheet1 Chart 1
    OldSourcePath = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1).LinkFormat.SourceFullName

    Set ofd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    With ofd
        .InitialFileName = initDir
        .AllowMultiSelect = False

        If .Show = -1 Then
            '~~> Get the path of the newly selected workbook. It will be something like
            '   C:\Book2.xlsx
            sPath = .SelectedItems(1)

            '~~> Launch Excel
            Set oXLApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
            oXLApp.Visible = True

            '~~> Open the Excel File. Required to update the chart's source
            Set oXLWb = oXLApp.Workbooks.Open(sPath)

            '~~> Get the path "C:\MyFile.xlsx" from
            '~~> say "C:\MyFile.xlsx!Sheet1![MyFile.xlsx]Sheet1 Chart 1"
            OldPath = Split(OldSourcePath, "!")(0)

            '~~> Get just the filename "MyFile.xlsx"
            oldFileName = GetFilenameFromPath(OldPath)
            '~~> Get just the filename "Book2.xlsx" from the newly
            '~~> Selected file
            newFileName = GetFilenameFromPath(.SelectedItems(1))

            '~~> Replace old file with the new file
            NewSourcePath = Replace(OldSourcePath, oldFileName, newFileName)

            'Debug.Print NewSourcePath

            '~~> Change the source and update
            ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1).LinkFormat.SourceFullName = NewSourcePath
            ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1).LinkFormat.Update
            DoEvents

            '~~> Close Excel and clean up
            oXLWb.Close (False)

            Set oXLWb = Nothing
            oXLApp.Quit
            Set oXLApp = Nothing
        End If
    End With

    Set ofd = Nothing
End Sub

Public Function GetFilenameFromPath(ByVal strPath As String) As String
    If Right$(strPath, 1) <> "\" And Len(strPath) > 0 Then
        GetFilenameFromPath = _
        GetFilenameFromPath(Left$(strPath, Len(strPath) - 1)) + Right$(strPath, 1)
    End If
End Function
```